# How to display an image full screen on my second monitor (raspberry pi 4)

Tags: python, pi-4, fbi

I am using RPi 4 and running two monitors.
I want to display an image on the second screen using Python or Linux command line. I have tried but I couldn't do this with fbi(it displays on the both).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using slmPy (https://github.com/wavefrontshaping/slmPy).

Works good for me with a projector as a second monitor on the RPi4.

SlmPy uses NumpyArrays as input. Therefore, I suggest using opencv for loading images as its native representation of images are numpy arrays.